# what is the influence of different resistors in circuit of moving coil through magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism

I did an experiment with a coil (induction wand) going through a constant magnetic field and the circuit the coil was in, had a resistor in it. 
When this resistor was changed to a resistor with higher resistance, the induced energy measured lowered. However, Faradays law doesnt say that induced emf depends on resistance in circuit of the coil. The induced electrical energy should thus be the same with different resistors in the circuit of the coil. 
But it wasn't...

Now I do get that with a higher resistance there will be a lower current, according to Ohm’s law of V=IR. A lower current will lower P = I V and lower the integral of P(t) d(t) which is Energy. And with this path of thinking the energy does lower, but where do I go wrong?

What is the explanation of my results giving a lower energy with higher resistances?

And what exactly is induced there? The energy right? Or voltage or current?

Comment: What do you mean by *induced energy*? Faraday's Law gives a value for *induced emf*. Nothing else is *induced* by the changing magnetic flux linkage by the circuit.

Comment: The induced emf causes electrical energy in the circuit right? I wanted to measure the amount of electrical energy caused by the induced emf, thus 'induced energy'.

Comment: The flow of electrical current dissipates energy. The rate of dissipation is $P=I^2R=V^2/R$. Larger resistance, smaller power. There is an emf whether or not there is any dissipation of energy. ... It might be that the emf changes during your experiment. If you want an explanation of your results you need to provide more information about your experiment and your results.

Comment: In that case, I think I calculated the energy induced by the emf wrong.. My hypothesis was that the loss of kinetic energy of a moving coil through a magnetic field (Set-up https://www.pasco.com/prodCatalog/EM/EM-8099_induction-wand/index.cfm)  would be equal to the energy caused by the induced emf. I calculated this energy by measuring the voltage in the circuit of the coil, using it in the formula P=V^2/R and taking the integral of P to get to E.  But using this method I got a lower energy value when using a larger resistor. Was my method of calculation not correct?

Comment: Your link is to a description of an instrument, not a description of your experiment nor your results.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you when repeated the experiment with a resistor of larger resistance moving the coil at the same speed then the induced emf $V$ will be the same.
If the resistance of the circuit is $R$ then the electrical power is $\frac {V^2}{R}$.
This confirms your prediction that, if the induced emf is constant, as the resistance of the circuit increases the electrical power dissipated decreases.

Now consider where that electrical power comes from.
The induced emf is due to something, you?, applying a force on the coil.
That force does work to move the coil through the magnetic field and in doing so induces the emf in the circuit which induces a current in the circuit.
Lens tells you that the induced current produces a magnetic field which tries to oppose the motion producing it which is you moving the coil through the magnetic field.
The smaller the induced current the smaller the opposing force and hence the smaller the force that you have to apply.
If you apply a smaller force then the power input from you is smaller and the electrical power produced is also smaller.
This happens when the resistance of the resistor is larger,

The extreme case is having a break in the circuit so there is an emf induced but no induced current.
No electrical power is produced.
To induced current means that there is no force opposing the motion of the coil, ie you do not have to do any work pushing the coil through the magnetic field.